# ASP.NET Entity Framework boolean returns false while the value is true in the database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm currently developing an API using ASP.NET and Entity Framework. I'm trying to get one record from the database. The record contains one column named `IsActivated` which is set as `1` (true). However, the boolean is set to `False` whenever I write it to my console.

My code is as follows:

**User.cs**

```
public class User : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    public string Password { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: class, IEntity
{
    private EntityContext _context;

    public Repository(EntityContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> Get(
        Expression<Func<T, bool>>? filter = null, 
        params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
    {
        IQueryable<T> dbSet = _context.Set<T>();

        if (filter != null)
            dbSet = dbSet.Where(filter);

        foreach (var expression in includes)
            dbSet = dbSet.Include(expression);

        return await dbSet
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

**AuthService.cs**

```
public class AuthService
{
    private readonly UserRepository _userRepository;

    private readonly PasswordHasher<User> _passwordHasher;

    private readonly TokenService _tokenService;

    public AuthService(UserRepository userRepository, TokenService tokenService)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;

        _passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<User>();

        _tokenService = tokenService;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetUserByEmail(string email)
    {
        List<User> users = await _userRepository.Get(user => user.Email == email);

        if (users.Count <= 0)
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();

        return users.First();
    }
}
```

The return value is correct except for the `IsActivated`. EntityFramework does update the column correctly...

**What I already tried**

1. Updating EntityFramework from 6.0.13 to 7.0.0, it broke everything (probably because I'm on dotnet 6).
2. Downgrading EntityFramework from 6.0.13 to 6.0.10, didn't do anything.
3. Retrieving the data from the database through a newly created method just to test, didn't work.

Comment: Post and accept your own answer below and that's how Stack Overflow works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I assigned a variable to it self in the User constructor rather than assigning the given value...